# Enabling Line Wrap in react-native-syntax-highlighter

Tags: javascript, react-native

For anyone that uses the `react-native-syntax-highlighter library`, have you been able to figure out how to wrap lines? This library is different from the `react-syntax-highlighter`, I tried the solution in the question posted about it but it didn't work for me.

I've tried using the `wrapLongLines` and `wrapLines` properties but no use. I've tried modifying the syntax library `CSS` and wrapping the `SyntaxHighlighter` in a View with word-wrapping enabled but still nothing. It looks like the problem comes from the library itself, but I want to make sure I'm not missing a quick solution.

```
<SyntaxHighlighter
language = 'javascript'
style = {syntax}
highlighter = "hljs"
wrapLongLines = {true}
wrapLines = {true} 
>
  {item.code}
 </SyntaxHighlighter>
```

Update: It looks like the library simply just does not allow it

Comment: It doesn't look like those props are available in the native version. I know it says that it accepts all the same props as the non-native version, but the last new version of native was 2 years before the last published version of non-native, so perhaps 4 years ago it did accept all the same props and just fell behind?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe I'll try replicating in a new environment and see if it works outside the context of my project. You're right, it does say it accepts the same props as non-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found somewhat of a solution by modifying, then building with `npm run build`, src/index.js in the `react-native-syntax-highlighter library`. Inside the `createNativeElement` function, in the `Text` component returned by it, applying `wordWrap: 'break-word'` to its style actually wrapped lines!

The library strings multiple `Text` components together into this one `Text` component. This is a "half solution" though, the library itself needs changing:

```
const children = childrenCreator(node.children, style.color || defaultColor);
return (
  <Text key={key} style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }}>
    {children}
  </Text>);
```